Error 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found with command pod spec lint
I have a React native app with native code (is not library project).
I add a .podspec file because I want to publish a npm package.
When I run command pod spec lint i have this error

ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  appname/ios/folderappname/AppDelegate.h:1:9: error: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

When I run my project with Xcode or with command
npx react-native run-android
it all works.
My version of react native is 0.76.2.
